# Bootstrap Top Glyph Link wont work when page is condensed

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink

so this is a really odd problem and I've tried searching for it but I honestly don't know what to search for anymore.

I am creating a website that lists products and you can add them to your wish list. The links (Hearts) to add products works great every time UNLESS the page is condensed so that only two columns (or less) show. When the page is condensed to two columns the top heart link doesn't work. The weird thing is every other link besides the ones on the top row will work! It seems like it makes the top one unclickable for some reason. Another thing is that all of the navigation and pagination links above and below the top row work fine. Here's the website: http://timtroiano.com/chalk/. If you need me to post any code let me know. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why aren't you using bootstraps `row` ?

Comment: And the reason you can't click on them is because upon screen resize, all your `.col-md-4` divs are reducing to 1px in height and stacking on top of each other which ends up overlapping half of the item(s) on the top row.

Comment: Thank you for the comments! Removing .col-md-4 worked but now my columns aren't spaced evenly in the container. Any suggestions on how I might be able to fix this without completely redoing my grid system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not that the link isn't working, it's that there are elements covering it so you can't click it.

here is the code in question:

[image: badbootstrap]

bootstrap is breaking because you're using full-width columns and they're all stacking on top of the first row like so:

[image: linkblocked]

you need to rethink how you're thinking about your html - each item shouldn't be it's own column (and they aren't functioning as columns). not to mention you are using more than the max column width bootstrap allows (12).

it's working currently because you have `float` rules which override what the column rules would have done, so one soln would be to just remove the `col-md-4` class entirely from each of the divs above. let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: Ah that makes perfect sense, thank you! I remember now I did that to keep the img divs spaced equally throughout the body container. The links now work but the columns are all aligning to the left and it looks odd when you're in-between sizes. Do you have any ideas for how I can keep the even spacing without losing functionality? If you refresh the page you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: this is where you'd want to use rows & bootstrap's grid system. you had `col-md-4` before which allows 3 columns per row, and you can add `col-sm-6` also so that at smaller screen sizes, there are 2 columns per row.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid has a good overview of this, should have everything you need.

Comment: Wow that's fantastic, I marked your answer as correct since you basically covered everything. I am now using 'col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4' to go from 3->2->1. The only thing I would like to add is when it gets down to one I'm not sure how to center the div in the container. Any ideas? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: yw! you should use `margin: 0 auto` for the div; if you only want to center the div when at a certain screen width use a media query: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

e.g. `@media (max-width: 700px) { div {margin: 0 auto; } }`